# Create better Base DAO class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I created a DAO class which is base class for all other DAO classes.

I use Spring Framework 4 and Hibernate 4.

**Question:** Is there anything that could be done better?

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<E, I extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<E, I> {
    private Class<E> entityClass;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public GenericDaoImpl(Class<E> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<E> findAll() throws DataAccessException {
        return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass).list();
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E find(I id) {
        return (E) getCurrentSession().get(entityClass, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void create(E e) {
        getCurrentSession().save(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(E e)  {
        getCurrentSession().update(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(E e) {
        getCurrentSession().delete(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        getCurrentSession().flush();
    }
}
```

Sample DAO class which extends base DAO class is for example this one:

```
@Repository("articleDao")
public class ArticleDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<ArticleEntity, Long> implements ArticleDao {
    public ArticleDaoImpl(){
        super(ArticleEntity.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would shorten `getCurrentSession` to `getSession` which is clear enough.

Comment: @DavidHarkness It is the same as original name from `sessionFactory`. I don't think that it is an improvement.

Comment: Where is the Uses for `I`

Answer (score 2):

To be able to create a parameter-less constructor add the following code into your constructor. It will use reflection to set `entityClass`. This way you don't even need to worry about passing in a class type, you can extend out your generic DAO and its type will be set by parameterisation.

```
public GenericDaoImpl() {
    Type e = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) e;
    entityClass = (Class<E>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

This removes the need for having constructors in subclasses of your `GenericDAOImpl`.

Why don't you combine your create and update methods? It makes for easier service calls.

```
@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(E e){
    getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(e);
}
```

Hibernate will automatically make the determination whether a save or update call is appropriate. If your ID field is set, then perform an update, otherwise perform a save.

Also, I would remove `getCurrentSession()` from your interface and change the method to private. You shouldn't be accessing the Hibernate session from anywhere outside the DAO so there is no reason to expose out your `getCurrentSession()` method.